# Java Guava CartesianProduct

Tags: java, generics, guava, cartesian-product

I am exploring Java Guava Library by writing small snippets of code. Here is what I wrote  for finding the [**cartesian product**](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Cartesian_product.html) of n-sets. [**Documentation here**](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct%28java.util.List%29)

```
//allLists populated above
...
List<Set> interimList = new ArrayList<Set>();
for(List<String> tmp : allLists) //converting List<List> to List<Set> 
{
    Set interimSet   = new HashSet(tmp);
    interimList.add(interimSet);
}
System.out.println(interimList);
Sets.cartesianProduct(interimList);
```

But this is not compiling. The last line `Sets.cartesianProduct` is not accepting `List<Set>`. But according to documentation isn't that its signature?

`public static <B> Set<List<B>> cartesianProduct(List<? extends Set<? extends B>> sets)`

**ERROR MESSAGE:** `Cannot Resolve method cartesianProduct(java.util.List<java.util.Set)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you have created a raw `Set`, instead of a generic one.

What happens is you're trying to pass a `List<Set<Object extends String>>` to the `Sets.cartesianProduct()` and this is why you're receiving a compile-type error.

This compiles:

```
List<Set<String>> interimList = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();
//converting List<List<String>> to List<Set<String>>
for (List<String> tmp : allLists) { 
    Set<String> interimSet   = new HashSet<String>(tmp);
    interimList.add(interimSet);
}
System.out.println(interimList);
Sets.cartesianProduct(interimList);
```